# Given a generating function with "zeros", can one derive the function for ONLY the "zeros"?

Tags: nt.number-theory, generating-functions

If I have an generating function (GF) --- ordinary or exponential --- defining a series with at least one coefficient equal to zero, is there a general method to find the "inverse GF", *i.e.*, the GF defining the series which **only** includes those zeros?

For example [a very simplified one!], if I have the "odd number exponential GF"

$EG(2n+1;x) = x^1 + x^3 + x^5 + x^7 + \dots,$

how can I use it to derive the "even number exponential GF"

$EG'(2n;x) = 1 + x^2 + x^4 + \dots$

?

Thanks!
Kieren.

---

Addendum: For my trivial example, above, the inversion is (d'oh!) simply to subtract that series from the "unit series" (where all coefficients are 1), *i.e.*,

$(1 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + \dots)
- (x^1 + x^3 + x^5 + \dots)
= 1 + x^2 + x^4 + \dots.$

Ergo, this "inversion" is trivial to implement --- and the problem is reduced to the open question referenced below (*i.e.*, to determine whether either the original GF or its "inverse" has any zeros).

Now my question is more specific: For **arbitrary** coefficients, is there a reasonable algorithm to derive the "inverted GF"?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan I have the opposite objection: it seems that such an operation (if efficient to implement) would be too useful to actually exist

Comment: What do you want as coefficients for the zero terms?  Do you always want 1?

Comment: Benjamin: Ultimately, it would be useful --- perhaps, as John points out, too useful to actually exist --- if the coefficients of the original sequence could be arbitrary (as opposed to all 1, as in my simple example), and the inversion would be all 1s. However, *any* inversion would be quite useful, in my opinion. Do you have an idea for an inversion algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

It is an open problem to determine whether there even exists an algorithm which determines whether a rational generating function has a coefficient equal to zero. See [this blog post](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/05/25/open-question-effective-skolem-mahler-lech-theorem/) by Terence Tao.

Comment: This is an interesting related question. Thank you for the link!

Comment: For rational power series in noncommuting variables it is undecidable whether  there is a non-zero coefficient. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139715/is-it-decidable-whether-the-support-of-a-rational-mathbbz-series-is-a-regul/139729#139729

Comment: Note Tao's post is a proof that in one variable the support always is a regular language.