# For which recurrence relations is it decidable whether a formal power series has a maximal zero coefficient?

Tags: nt.number-theory, power-series, recurrences

In [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965806/can-one-prove-that-a-generating-function-has-infinitely-many-coefficients-equali), I asked whether one can prove that a generating function has infinitely many coefficients equal to zero. The answer given (and accepted) to that rather broad question was “No”.

[The respondent](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23550/john-leo) raised an interesting refinement to the question, which seemed MO-hard to me, so I'm asking it here.

**Question.** Let $G$ be a generating function (ordinary, exponential, or otherwise) such as
$$
G(a_n;\, x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n,
$$
where the coefficients $a_n$ satisfy some known recurrence relation R (linear or otherwise). For which R is it decidable whether $G$ has a maximal zero coefficient $a_m=0$? Put another way, for which R can it be shown that $G$ has infinitely many coefficients equal to zero?

Some possibly related posts:
[Is it decidable whether the support of a rational $\mathbb{Z}$-series is a regular language?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139715/is-it-decidable-whether-the-support-of-a-rational-mathbbz-series-is-a-regul)
[Given a generating function with "zeros", can one derive the function for ONLY the "zeros"?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140514/given-a-generating-function-with-zeros-can-one-derive-the-function-for-only-t)

Comment: The answer by 
Qiaochu to the second question that you linked answers that it is an open problem for linear recurrence relations.

Comment: But it doesn't seem to me that his answer is dependent on whether the coefficients satisfy a recurrence relation — just a “rational generating function”. Am I missing something?

Comment: A sequence satisfies a linear recurrence iff the generating function is a rational function.

Comment: Ah… Well, if you write your comment up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Rational_generating_function

Comment: The question should instead be closed as duplicate.

Comment: But it's not a duplicate — the other question asked about "flipping" the coefficients, and Qiaochu gave a _related_ answer (which didn't answer the original question).

Comment: What does the power series have to do with it? You have a recurrence relation giving a sequence ( with some initial conditions), that is all that really matters. If you want to know about linear that is one thing. "Or otherwise" allows for all manner of possibilities

Comment: I'm new to generating functions, so the fact that they apparently don't matter in this question is over my head. I have developed generating functions (both ordinary and exponential) that give, as their "zeros", exactly the twin prime separators — I was wondering if there was anything useful I could do with them. Apparently not.